# Call controller from controller passing arguments

Tags: modules, params, action

new to CraftCMS - I'm building a website that has to handle two different APIs, where the user logs into API-1 and after succeeding the website has to call an other API checking for a status while using data that was returned from the first API.

I started to set-up two controllers to handle the requests of each API separately. What I have to do is to fire an action from controller-1 (login-callback) and if login was ok I would like to directly fire an action from controller-2 handling the second API (without the user having to take action by clicking a button). Some research showed that I can do

```php
Craft::$app->runAction('mymodule/contoller/method-name-call');
```

That works so far but I have to pass some data as params and found out that the call then should look like:

```php
Craft::$app->runAction('mymodule/contoller/method-name-call', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

But I can't manage to access the passed arguments :/
Even tried to pass to pass as a GET-Param like:

```php
Craft::$app->runAction('mymodule/contoller/method-name-call?foo=bar');
```

and then access via:

```php
$request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
$data = $request->get('foo');
```

but no success..

Can somebody advice me how to access the passed params in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After crawling the Yii repository issues I found out how to pass and retrieve the arguments.

In case someone else is struggeling with this I'd like to share this little summary:

```php
# Controller-1
public function actionSomeMethodName()
{
    // call action of controller-2
    Craft::$app->runAction('mymodule/controller-2/method-other-controller', ['paramsWrapperName' => ['someKey' => 'some value'] ]);

    // do something ...
}
```

The argument-name `$paramsWrapperName` has to match the *outter-array-index* where you make the call and you have to *type-cast* the argument as `array` otherwise you get a baaaaaad baad exception

```php
# Controller-2
public function actionMethodOtherController(array $paramsWrapperName)
{
    // do something with $paramsWrapperName
}
```

Of course instead of *paramsWrapperName* a simple *params* or simular makes more sense, just wanted to make it clearer that way..